# Can I do addView in onDraw of MyLayout?

Tags: android

I am new for android. I want to add image button in onDraw. I wonder if I can do like this. I don't have compile error. But simulator says, "Unfortunately MyApp has stopped."
My second question is how can I add button at x, y location in screen?
There is no location parameters in addView.

```
protected class MyLayout extends LinearLayout {
    ImageButton button;
    public MyLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        button = new ImageButton(context);
        button.setImageBitmap(buttonBitmap); // buttonBitmap is loaded in onCreate
    }
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        addView(button);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not be adding a button to a custom linearlayout in the onDraw() override function. onDraw is called periodically (for example when the element is resized). So you will be adding the same button EACH time onDraw() is called. And you will get an error if you add the same item more than once.

What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to just add a button to a linear layout, you can do so without extending a layout.

Comment: location of button is changed, created, and destroyed dynamically in runtime. Where is good place to put that? How can you do without extending a layout?

Comment: I can do addView in constructor. I think I can change, destroy in onTouchEvent and call onDraw by invalidate. Anyway, how can you do without extending a layout?

Comment: Yes, If you have to create a custom LinearLayout, running addView in the constructor would be the best idea. But at that point your just better off using LinearLayout itself, and adding and removing it dynamically from the level above.

Comment: As for moving the button dynamically (I have not tested this). But it would stand to reason that: 
`Button b = (Button)yourLayoutInstanceName.getChildAt(index);`
`b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(...));`
`yourLayoutInstanceName.invalidate();`

You set the new layout for the button then invalidate everything in the layout, forcing everything (including the button) to redraw.

Comment: There is no x, y field in LinearLayout. So, I inherited MyLayout from AbsoluteLayout. Now I can change position of button at runtime. But Android doesn't recommend using absolute layout. Is there better way to place button at runtime? I am wondering how I can place object at x, y position without using absolute layout.

Comment: If you want to use x and y position to place the element, absolute layout is what you want to use. Absolute Layout isn't recommended **because** using x and y for positioning is inherently a bad idea when your supporting multiple screens. If you want to use x,y for positioning use absolute layout (you can get it to work with multiple screen types with a lot of effort). But I would advise trying to use another layout for positioning.